# Excel Duplicate Finder in Seperate Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I've found this piece of code online and tried to modify it to do what i want. It works in a very basic way, where you assign it as a macro to a Form button, to find duplicates in 6 seperate columns, but is there a way of tidying up the code, and possibly automating it, so i don't have to press a form button to run the macro every time ?

```
Sub Check_Dups()

'Declaring variables
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim Source As Range
Dim Source2 As Range
Dim Source3 As Range
Dim Source4 As Range
Dim Source5 As Range
Dim Source6 As Range
'Initializing source range
Set Source = Range("E8:E105")
Set Source2 = Range("F8:F105")
Set Source3 = Range("G8:G105")
Set Source4 = Range("H8:H105")
Set Source5 = Range("I8:I105")
Set Source6 = Range("J8:J105")

'Removing any previous formatting from the source
Source.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Source2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Source3.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Source4.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Source5.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Source6.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

'Looping through each cell in the source range
For Each Cell In Source

    'Checking whether value in cell already exist in the source range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source, Cell) > 1 Then

        'Highlighting duplicate values in red color
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If
Next
'Looping through each cell in the source range
For Each Cell In Source2

    'Checking whether value in cell already exist in the source range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source2, Cell) > 1 Then

        'Highlighting duplicate values in red color
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If
Next
'Looping through each cell in the source range
For Each Cell In Source3

    'Checking whether value in cell already exist in the source range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source3, Cell) > 1 Then

        'Highlighting duplicate values in red color
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If
Next
'Looping through each cell in the source range
For Each Cell In Source4

    'Checking whether value in cell already exist in the source range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source4, Cell) > 1 Then

        'Highlighting duplicate values in red color
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If
Next
'Looping through each cell in the source range
For Each Cell In Source5

    'Checking whether value in cell already exist in the source range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source5, Cell) > 1 Then

        'Highlighting duplicate values in red color
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If
Next
'Looping through each cell in the source range
For Each Cell In Source6

    'Checking whether value in cell already exist in the source range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source6, Cell) > 1 Then

        'Highlighting duplicate values in red color
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: *is there a way of tidying up the code, and possibly automating it* Something faster that just 1 single click?

Comment: i know that conditional formatting could do it, but as vba it just seems more efficient

Comment: Considering you want to avoid clicking a button on a form you would want to capture `Change` events on your worksheet. But this would (almost) be the same as volatile conditional formatting. I don't see why you would not use CF in this case.

Comment: Your code doesn't find duplicates in 6 columns. It finds them in one column. "Find duplicates in 6 columns" isn't an adequate task description. Define the "original" and the "duplicate". Assuming originals can only be in column E and duplicates can be anywhere in the 6 columns, do you want the originals coloured if there are duplicates? Or do you want both originals and duplicates coloured? Can originals be in columns other than column E? and if you only want the originals coloured, in which sequence should the search proceed?

Comment: The data is a duty sheet for work, based on 6 days. So i have 6 columns, E - I and Rows 8 - 105. I want it to find duplicates in the individual columns from rows 8 - 105. The original and duplicate would need to be hilighted in the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

Some other ways to automate a macro are `WorkSheet_Change` and `Workbook_Open` events, but I would stick with `Button_Click` to initiate your macro. 
The below code can be use to loop through the range in each column and color duplicate values using `AutoFilter`. If you want to color each group a different color, you can use the randomized RGB line of code.

```
Sub ColorDuplicates_wRGB()
'This macro loops thru each cell, if the cell has duplicates in the range, it filters the range using the cell value,
'then colors the visible cells in the range Red or with a unique color using RGB Colors.
'xlNone in the If statement, skips previous colored cells.
'Works with both sorted and unsorted data.

Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range, colr As String, i As Long 'Define your variables

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'I hate to see the screen flickering

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'identify the worksheet variable; you will need to change the sheet reference

    For i = 5 To 9 'To loop through each column
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, i), ws.Cells(105, i))
        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'clear interior color for all cells in range

        For Each cel In rng 'Loop
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel.Value) > 1 And cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                'Filter using cel.Value
                rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cel.Value

                colr = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                'If you want different colors for each duplicate group use the next line
                'colr = RGB(Int((255 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1), Int((255 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1), Int((255 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1))

                'Select the visible cells in range and color, the -1 removes the blank row at the end caused by Offset
                rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = colr

                rng.AutoFilter 'reset filter
            End If
        Next cel
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb here, but i'm a bit of a newbie with VBA. Does this code look for duplicates in the columns individually, or as a collective of all 6 columns ? Because the sheet i'm using is 6 day columns, Monday - Friday (E-I).

Comment: If you are using 6 columns then change the 9  to 10 . The For i = 5 To 9 loops through each column, e.g. 5 = Col E, rng is set for column, and the code is ran for each column rng

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate your help. I now understand it, and it's perfect for what i need, and very much tidier than what i had been trying.

Comment: I'm having an error message. `Variable not Defined`.... then it hilights the 'i' variable

Comment: @BrianDavies: See my edit, you probably have `Option Explicit`, so I added the variable `i` declaration.